# Changing fragment get IllegalStateException must not be null in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, illegalstateexception

Hi I am getting some information from web with coroutines in my program When the information is receiving I change the fragment In this case the program crashes and the Null error takes the following options

```
progress.isIndeterminate = false
adapter = CircularAdapter(itemsData, this@CircularFragment)
rc.adapter = adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
swipe_refresh.visibility = View.VISIBLE
lyt_progress.visibility = View.GONE
swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = false
```

This is my code I even cancel the job in OnDestroyView, but I still get an error

```
 private var job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
    launch {
                val operation = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                   try {
                       ...
                       for (myTable in table) {
                           val rows: Elements = myTable.select("tr")
                           activity?.runOnUiThread{
                               progress.isIndeterminate = false
                           }
                           for (i in 1 until rows.size) {
                               progress.progress = i                               
                               itemsData.add(...)

                           }
                       }
                   }catch (e: Exception){
                       activity?.runOnUiThread{
                           val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                           navController.navigate(R.id.noVPNFragment)
                       }
                   }
                }
                operation.await() // wait for result of I/O operation without blocking the main thread

                // update views
                activity?.runOnUiThread{
                    adapter = CircularAdapter(itemsData, this@CircularFragment)
                    rc.adapter = adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    swipe_refresh.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    lyt_progress.visibility = View.GONE
                    swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }

    override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            job.cancel()
        }

        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()
            job.cancel()
        }
```

UPDATE:
logcat:

```
02-21 12:52:48.268 16218-16218/ir.mahdi.circulars.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.mahdi.circulars.test, PID: 16218
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: progress must not be null
        at ir.mahdi.circulars.Fragments.CircularFragment$getCirculars$1$operation$1$1.run(CircularFragment.kt:118)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: when and where do you get that progress? cause from the stack it's the source of the problem, can we have the full code of the fragment?

Comment: @git it is better to use [predefined coroutine scopes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) to launch coroutines into instead of managing the scope manually, *viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope* would be the right choice for your case. Probably this can solve your crash.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, it seems that `progress.isIndeterminate = false`
 is the reason of error. Looks like `progress` has not been initialised. Maybe you forgot `findViewById()` or what ever you use for view binding.

Comment: no if i change progress to null check with ? `progress?.isIndeterminate = false` program get crash on another control that is on runOnUiThread